# ADUC to a domain outside forest?

Tags: windows, active-directory

I'm trying to set up an environment where our support can access multiple of our AD-domains from the same server.

So we have this toolbox server in Domain-A where ADUC is installed.
Domain-B and Domain-C are in different forests but the DCs are reachable over the network.

The support person has delegated access to all domains but with different user accounts and passwords. We don't want to create a trust between the domains.

I've tried to add the remote domains in the DNS and/or host-file of the toolbox-server, and also started ADUC with "run-as".

Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the correct/full network access, you don't need a trust. You can open a command prompt with the other domain credentials:

`runas /netonly /user:DomainB\Username cmd.exe`

Then run dsa.msc from that command prompt, and right-click and connect to DomainB. DNS obviously needs to be setup for those domains (stub domain or forwarder).

Comment: It kind of work, but maybe it comes down to the server they are jumping from. The first command works and they can authenticate. However they then get a UAC login where they need to write their DomainA-Credentials. After that a cmd comes up and you can write dsa.msc - that only starts as a black box. Is there a oneliner for this? Or maybe PS with get-credentials?

Comment: Another note, we have forwarders for the domains and I can see that LDAP traffic is being sent and received but still only the "black box" as dsa.msc and then the normal windows appcrash log. I can run other applications through the "run as-cmd" like notepad etc

Comment: If I turn off UAC I get the error "Naming information cannot be located because: The user name or password is incorrect"

Comment: Another edit (can't edit the answers after 5min, kinda annoying).
If I let the app crash so a "empty" ADUC starts I can change domain successfully

Comment: Edit 9034: I've solved it with Powershell:
`Import-Module RunAs
RunAs powershell.exe -netOnly -user $cred -arguments "dsa.msc /domain=DomainB"`